# Should I use the md5 password of a user to verify his account through email?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am creating a register form and I will have an email verification. The email will have an activation link that will update verified column from 0 to 1.
Since the user's password is hashed with md5 I thought instead of creating a new column with a random number to use as verification, I thought to use his password.

So instead of *domain.com/verification.php?token=new_random_number* I will have *domain.com/verification.php?token=md5*

How do you find this ?

This is of course just to avoid one column.

Comment: Pedantic: MD5 isn't encryption, it's hashing.

Comment: Also, why aren't you salting your hashes? If you don't and someone obtains the hashes, you're more susceptible to rainbow tables.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think md5 might produce some characters that would break or be illegal in a URL.

Comment: @Brian Glaz: Not if you use the hex serialization.

Comment: @icktoofay thank you for this. So should I use this with salt ?

Comment: Depending on what you're protecting behind that login, you probably shouldn't be using MD5 either, it's trivially brute-force-able. At the very least use one of the SHA2 variants, but preferably use something a bit more future-proof like BCrypt.

Comment: I don't know, I would probably use another table with the date/time row created, user ID and a hash value of the password, microtime and a salt, and then purge all rows that are older than a certain date/time (say, 48 hours or 7 days). And Blowfish (using crypt()) is a better password hashing algorithm than MD5 at this point. Of course, reviewing this you could do the same thing with a Key column on your User table, unless you wanted to preserve accounts that were setup but never confirmed.

Comment: @Nikolai: I wouldn't use the password hash as a token, but yes, I'd salt your passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a new random ID for the explicit purpose of the email, then you can invalidate/clear the ID after the user has performed the account management action.

Comment: +1 to this. MD5 is barely secure enough for anything if the database it's stored in remains uncompromised. To send the hash plaintext in an email (and possibly plaintext over HTTP depending on how you format the link) is absolute madness.

Comment: What function will let me create a url safe random number ? And also, what is a suitable way to use instead of md5 ?

Comment: url safe random number ?? Numbers don't need to be escaped in urls. use my method below , and save your time / resources.

Comment: Yes but how to create this random id? What is the function that you suggest me ?

Comment: if you generated a random number , then you need to save it on DB. thus consuming an extra DB column...

Comment: md5(uniqid('', true)) is one option. Also check out some of the user comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @Nikolai, Create another table for verification (storing userID and token), don't create a column in your users table.

Comment: @Christian Varga : what is the reason for this?

Comment: I don't think that matters, I mean you woudn't have multiple authentication emails active at the same time for the one user. And if they do-request to resend a new activation email, but click an old link then that's fair enough to have the old ones as "expired".

Comment: @Nikolai it's all about normalisation. The token is used once per user then cleared. This means for every validated user, the token field is not required and would be NULL if it was a column in the users table. Lots of NULL fields always indicates bad DB design. There's actually a word to describe this but it escapes me right now. Read up about normalisation, this will make more sense then.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like :

`$secret_word ='COMPLEX-WORD-HERE';

$validation_token = substr(md5($user_password.$secret_word),0,10);`

I highly recommend using username instead, since it's unique per user 
101% secure :)